# How to return XML to the Response stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, ihttphandler

I'm trying to return an xml string from a IHttpHandler to a like this:

```
context.Response.Write(xml);
```

When I receive the response in my .aspx.cs I try to load the document as follows:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(xmlString);
```

but I get an `Illegal Characters in Path` error message.

I've also tried

```
context.Response.Write(context.Server.HtmlEncode(xml));
```

and

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(Server.HtmlDecode(xmlString));
```

but I get the same message. Is there any way I can return XML from my IHttpHandler?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're doing... especially the whole "receive the response in my .aspx.cs". Where does `xmlString` come from? Can you outline the flow of your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace this:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(xmlString);
```

with this:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

Answer (score 1):

XDocument.Load(String) takes a file path.  You want to use one of the overloads that accepts a Reader object.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml"`

Obviously also make sure the XML is well formed, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) has an example of returning XML from a HTTP Handler.

Try putting the XML into a validator (or open in a browser) to highlight any issues.